# условное подключение модуля Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

Как условно (в зависимости от версии QT) подключить модуль в проект (в файле .pro)?

Речь идет о ключе QT += core xml (и т.д.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18663435/4711135

Comment: решение в https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663331/how-to-check-the-selected-version-of-qt-in-a-pro-file/18663435#18663435 спасибо Alexander Chermin